# Python 3.4 Tkinter - Object has no attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm making a program to kind of simulate a console. This is my code so far (I started it today, learning about Tkinter, although I'm not sure if Tkinter the best choice):

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, bg = 'black')
        self.bottomframe = Frame(master, bg = 'black')
        self.elabel = Label(master, text = '>', bg = 'black', font = 'system', fg = 'white')
        self.einput = Entry(master, bd =0, bg = 'black', font = 'system', fg = 'white', command = self.update_text())

        # Packing
        self.frame.pack()
        self.bottomframe.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.elabel.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.einput.pack(side = LEFT)
    def update_text(self):
        self.einput.insert(0, '>')


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*/PycharmProjects/ConsoleDungeon/game.py", line 21, in <module>
    app = Game(root)
  File "C:/Users/*/PycharmProjects/ConsoleDungeon/game.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.einput = Entry(master, bd =0, bg = 'black', font = 'system', fg = 'white', command = self.update_text())
  File "C:/Users/*/PycharmProjects/ConsoleDungeon/game.py", line 17, in update_text
    self.einput.insert(0, '>')
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'einput'
```

and one more thing: in the line

```
self.einput = Entry(master, bd =0, bg = 'black', font = 'system', fg = 'white', command = self.update_text())
```

I wasn't sure about how to use the **command** argument.

Comment: remove the parentheses from your `command` argument and it will solve both errors

Comment: the entry widget doesn't have a command argument? are you sure you dont mean validatecommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what a `command` argument is *supposed* to do on an `Entry` widget, but that's where the problem lives alright. `command` expects a callable (that is, a function NAME, not the calling of that function). The way your program flows right now is:

```
create App
make App.frame
make App.bottomframe
make App.elabel
make App.einput
--> Oh, there's a function call in that declaration, gotta follow it before I
    finish making this object
------> The function call refers to an `App.einput`, but I don't have one of
        those (yet!) so we better throw an AttributeError
```